# Angular4 proxy config bad request

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, proxy

I'm trying to reach github api from my angular application.

Here's my proxy config:

```
{
  "/api/github/*": {
    "target": "https://api.github.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api/github": ""
    }
  }
}
```

So when I ping something like `http://localhost:4200/api/github/users/linus` from my angular service I'm supposed to be pointed `https://api.github.com/users/linus`. But each time this request is sent I get `400 BAD REQUEST`, which should't be the case as the api link is working fine.

Here's log from my app runtime that shows this proxy activity:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/github/users/linus" to "/users/linus"
[HPM] GET /api/github/users/linus ~> https://api.github.com
```

Comment: How do you expect this to work in production, where you won't use the angular-cli development server anymore, and thus won't have a proxy anymore? Why don't you send requests t github directly?

Comment: A 400 request means you're proxy is likely fine, but your call isn't. If it's a GET you're likely hitting an endpoint that just doesn't exist. If it's not GET you likely don't have the correct request options. Have you looked at what your XML is actually sending? The code that does that actual call would be more helpful.

Comment: @JBNizet Proxy works in production environment, and this is a pretty standard way to handle it.

Comment: @Z.Bagley that's exactly the problem as when the request is done manually everything works. How do I inspect the actual request sent by the proxy?

Comment: In your browser normally you can go to dev console (F12 in most) and under 'Network' you can see the requests. XHR is what you're looking for and if you click around you can see exactly what your request looks like.

Comment: I know what client request looks like. I mean the request sent from proxy